# Percentage share question?

Tags: percentages

Three Business partners share a business in the following percentages.

Person 1 = $40$%
Person 2 = $30$%
Person 3 = $30$%

Then p1 and p2 agreed to became $50-50$ on the business by purchasing the share of p3.

the business was valued at $9,000,000$. So $30$% of that will be $2,700,000$ for p3 share.

My question is how will $2,700,000$ be paid between p1&p2?

Comment: what have you attempted to solve it?

Comment: Person 1 needs $10\%$ and Person 2 needs $20\%$, $1:2$, so divide $2,700,000$ into 3 equal parts, Person 1 buys 1 part and Person 2 buys 2 parts